# getting null checkbox array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to delete all rows on the view page by selecting select all option. My jQuery code for select all is working fine but i am getting null array while I have created checkbox array.

```
<?php
if($total>0){
$i=1;
while($line_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($getResult)){                          
?>                                      
<tr title="<?=$row_title?>">
<td>                                                
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_id[]" value="<?=$line_data['id']?>" style="width:15px;">
<?=$i.".";?>
</td>
```

jQuery code

```
 function check_all_list(thisid){
       if($('#'+thisid).parent('span').attr('class')!='checked'){ 
         $('input[name^="checkbox_id"]').each(function(){ 
          $(this).parent('span').addClass('checked');
          $(this).attr('checked',true);
         });
       }else{ 
         $('input[name^="checkbox_id"]').each(function(){
          $(this).parent('span').removeClass('checked');
          $(this).attr('checked',false);
         });
       }

     }
```

Comment: the mysql extension is depreciated use mysqli or pdo

Comment: you need to defined checked attr. inside your input otherwise you get null array. check every thing..

Comment: I am using php 5.5.15. If i am not mistaken mysql is deprecated in php 7

Comment: @RimonKhan Select all checkbox is working fine. If i click on select all it checks all checkboxes

Comment: can ypu post your jQuery code as well please

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya I have posted jQuery code. Please go through it.

Comment: @RahulRana so where have you created the array ? because you said that "but i am getting array containing null values while I have created checkbox array."

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya I have created checkboxes with the same name. Just see in the php section.

Comment: @RahulRana no it's deprecated as of `5.5` and _removed_ in version `7.0`. And it is deprecated for a reason, so do not use it if you care about security, code quality and if you don't want to rewrite your code in a while.

Comment: @giorgio one of my friend is using php 5.4.7. he is also facing this issue.

Comment: Using mysql/mysqli has little to do with your current issue, it's just that you really _really_ should not use the mysql extension. Under no circumstances. Even if you're lazy or hate yourself. Just don't.

Comment: issue is not with mysql extension.when i click on select all option then all checkboxes are checked but if i wanna echo checkbox array it is showing null.

Comment: can anyone help me out as i m stuck in this issue, any help would be appreciated.